# Using launch4j to build executable with encoding option

Tags: encoding, executable-jar, launch4j

I'm trying to write korean to a txt file. I've done the coding part and exported project to runnable jar. 
When I run jar file using terminal as  Java -Dfile.encoding="UTF-8" -jar Utul.jar  it works perfectly fine.
Now I'm trying to make .exe using launch4j can anyone help me set this option? In output file I'm getting gibberish instead of Korean characters.

Answer (score 0):

I've got the answer now. I wasn't aware of the JVM options field under JRE tab. I included this option there and result was satisfactory.